# Zend db PDO not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

i ahve a problem with the folowing:

```
$sql = "SELECT e.*, c.name city_name, u.*, IF(l.item IS NULL, 0, 1) as iLike, DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%h:%i') hour, DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%d/%c/%Y') day,  DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%c') month
FROM `events` e
LEFT OUTER JOIN `like` l ON l.item = e.uuid AND l.user = :user
            LEFT OUTER JOIN city c ON c.city = e.city
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON u.user = e.user
            WHERE
             e.deleted = 0
            AND DATE(e.date) >= CURDATE()
            AND e.user = :user
            ORDER by e.date ASC
            ";
    $select = $eventsModel->getAdapter();
    $select->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $prepare = $select->query($sql, array('user'=>$this->user_id));
```

This code returns results if i hardcode :user to the query. Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT e.*, c.name city_name, u.*, IF(l.item IS NULL, 0, 1) as iLike, DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%h:%i') hour, DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%d/%c/%Y') day,  DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%c') month
            FROM `events` e
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `like` l ON l.item = e.uuid AND l.user = 23
            LEFT OUTER JOIN city c ON c.city = e.city
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON u.user = e.user
            WHERE
             e.deleted = 0
            AND DATE(e.date) >= CURDATE()
            AND e.user = 23
            ORDER by e.date ASC
            ";
    $select = $eventsModel->getAdapter();
    $select->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $prepare = $select->query($sql);
```

This only started happening when we moved our code to the new server, 
the new OS is Debian 6, squeze, mysql 5.5, PHP 5.3.21.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` instead `:user`, and `$this->user_id` instead of `array('user'=>$this->user_id)`

Furthermore, you can't bind data in `JOIN` statement, so `l.user = e.user`

```
$sql = "SELECT e.*, c.name city_name, u.*, IF(l.item IS NULL, 0, 1) as iLike, DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%h:%i') hour, DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%d/%c/%Y') day,  DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%c') month
            FROM `events` e
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `like` l ON l.item = e.uuid AND l.user = e.user
            LEFT OUTER JOIN city c ON c.city = e.city
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON u.user = e.user
            WHERE
             e.deleted = 0
            AND DATE(e.date) >= CURDATE()
            AND e.user = ?
            ORDER by e.date ASC
            ";
    $select = $eventsModel->getAdapter();
    $select->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $prepare = $select->query($sql, array($this->user_id));
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not feasible, the whole codebase should be rewriten to accommodate that change. We are aware that this works.

Comment: Also, another interesting thing is if we use :user only once, not 2 times in mysql query the query works.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that user is used twice, do you need to declare 2 element in your param array : `array('user'=>$this->user_id,'l.user'=>$this->user_id)`, or perhaps `array($this->user_id, $this->user_id)`

Comment: in general, i could fix the issue by modifying the queryin a correct way, l.user = e.user. But this issue started popping up also on other places where we don't use the same code. We are wondering what changed. Or what is the general probelm, WHY it worked before and now it does not.